# Absolute indices from two data sets

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two data sets A and B, where A describe its section, B describe its location in that section.

A = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

B = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

I wanted to get an absolute index that describe their overall location in set C:

C = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

How do I derive a generic formula for C dependent on A and B? Arithmetic progression so far didn't help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "section", here? "$A$ describes its section" - the section of what?

Comment: Do I interpret correctly that you need a function $f(a,b)$ that has the properties
$$
f(0,0) = 0
$$
$$
f(0,1) = 1
$$
$$
f(0,2) = 2
$$
$$
f(1,0) = 3
$$
etc. ?

Comment: Sorry, I might be a little unclear, section here is referring to another external data sets, A & B are its properties of indices. And you're correct for the `f(a,b)`

Comment: In that case, this problem becomes essentially the same as this (but with different numerical values) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607759/finding-index-values-based-on-coordinate/3607828#3607828

Comment: Do you think you can solve it yourself, looking at the example? I even used the same notation for the function ...

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of the example, what if the x value only increases every 3 steps?

Comment: Never mind the steps. The order in which the data is given, does not matter. You can easily see that when $y$ increases by $1$, $f$ increases also by $1$. And when $x$ increases by $1$, by how much does $f$ increase?

Comment: If I understands correctly, it's also `1`? And that makes `c=3`. But that doesn't give the right result when `f(0,0)`.

Comment: Hint: compare $f(0,0)$ and $f(1,0)$. You see that $x$ has increase by one ...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?